# Codeigniter join from multiple databases

Tags: php, codeigniter, join, mysqli

Currently I have this not working code in my model:

```
$this->db_site->order_by('id', 'random');
$select = $this->db_site->get_where('berichten', array('beantwoord' => 0, 'gelezen' => 0));   
$this->db->join('replymessages', 'replymessages.msgid != berichten.id');
$this->db->join('replymessages', 'replymessages.time < '.time());
```

In this example the joins won’y work for the db_site query’s, is there a methode to do a join from an other database?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in method to do the join I'm afraid no. If databases are in the same database instance and you can grant a user access to both databases you can join that way by prefixing the database name on the table, i.e. database1.table1.

The alternative is to do the join the data using an in-php only solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what do you mean with an in-php only solution? Can you give an example? Unfortunattely the databases doesn't belong to the same user. So prefixing the database name won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

In `/config/database.php`

Create a new set of configuration for db connection

```
$db['seconddb']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['seconddb']['username'] = 'krish';
$db['seconddb']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['seconddb']['database'] = 'oOoOoO';
$db['seconddb']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['seconddb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['seconddb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['seconddb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['seconddb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['seconddb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['seconddb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['seconddb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['seconddb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['seconddb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['seconddb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Loading the db

```
$this->load->database('seconddb');
```

To connect to multiple databases

```
$db1 = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$db2 = $this->load->database('seconddb', TRUE);
```

and the syntax changes a lil bit for active records.

Instead of

```
$this->db->query();
```

you should use

```
$db1->query();
```

and

```
$db2->query();
```

so ,just edit your queries as required.